# Don't repeat keyof Type expression in generics

Tags: typescript

I don't want to repeat `keyof T` expression in here:

```
// This type is meant to achieve something like ReturnType<typeof Object.entries>
type ObjectEntries<T extends object> = [keyof T, T[keyof T]][];
```

So I do this but it doesn't work:

```
type ObjectEntries<T extends object, U = keyof T> = [U, T[U]][];
// Type 'U' cannot be used to index type 'T'
```

However if `U` extends to `keyof T`, it works but why?

```
type ObjectEntries<T extends object, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = [U, T[U]][];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`U extends X` means that `U` needs to be a type that extends `X`, it is also called a type constraint. If you leave it like this, `U` must be specified and you will get a compiler error if you don't specify it when instantiating `ObjectEntries`.

`U = X` means that if `U` is unspecified when instantiating `ObjectEntries` it will by default be `X`, but since `U` does not have any constraint, `U` could be any type whatsoever (for example `string`).

Constraints and defaults serve different purposes and so if you want `U` to default to `keyof T` so you don't have to specify it you need the  `= keyof T`, and if you also want to constrain `U` so only types that are subtypes of `keyof T` can be specified, you will need the `extends keyof T`. The constraint is what gives TyepScript enough information to know that it is safe to index `T` with `U`, since any specified type for `U` must be a subtype of `keyof T`